Clarification on the definition of co-functions
The definition of co-functions(Wiki) is as follows:
Definition: a function $f$ is cofunction of a function $g$ if $f(A) = g(B)$ whenever $A$ and $B$ are complementary angles.
I would like to confirm if it means that a function $f$ is cofunction of a function $g$ if and only if  $f(A) = g(B)$ for all cases where $A$ and $B$ are complementary angles?
Example: $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$ are not cofunctions even though $f(30) = 30 = g(60)$ and $60 + 30 = 90$, because there exists values of $x$ where we can't get $f(A) = g(B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are complementary angles?

Yes, it means for ALL $A,B$. In particular $f(x)=x,g(x)=x/2$ are not cofunctions because (for example) $f(45)\not=g(45)$.

It's another way of saying $f(x) = g(\frac{\pi}2-x)$ for all $x$ (or, if you're using degrees, $f(x) = g(90^{\circ}-x)$ for all $x$).
